# Boundary Value Analysis - When to use two value or three value?

Tags: testing, boundary

I had a few questions regarding boundary value analysis that I was hoping someone could help me with. I am learning this for a university exam based off of the ISTQB spec, not for real world application at the moment.

The first is - when should you assume to use two and three value methods of BVA? Is there any actual distinction as to when you should use one or the other, or does it depend on the specific question asked (in terms of an examination) and I would simply need to just know how to use both? Is there a default method to use?

Secondly, consider this possible question:

> A smart home app measures the average temperature in the 
>   house and provides feedback to the occupants for different 
>   average temperature ranges:
>   • Up to 10 C – Icy cool!
>   • 11 C to 15 C - Chilled out!
>   • 16 C to 19 C - Cool man!
>   • 20 C to 22 C –Too warm!
>   • Above 22 C - Hot and Sweaty!
>   Apply 3 point BVA to the above temperature ranges. How many test cases would you consider?

```
The answer that was provided was that:
    For 10 - we would test 9, 10, 11.  
    For 11 - we would test 10 (already tested), 11 (already tested), 12  
    For 16 - we would test 15, 16, 17  
    For 20 - we would test 19, 20, 21  
    For 22 - we would test 21 (already tested), 22, 23
    This would result in a a total of 12 test cases.
```

Can somebody please explain to me as to why we would test the upper boundary in the first partition (10 degrees), but not the upper boundaries in other valid partitions (such as 15, which would lead to us testing 14,15,16 or 19 leading to testing 18,19,20). Is this because the boundary of 10 is the only boundary within that partition, as the lower boundary is open?

As a follow on, assume that the boundaries were instead:

> • 0 C to 10 C – Icy cool!
>   • 11 C to 15 C - Chilled out!
>   • 16 C to 19 C - Cool man!
>   • 20 C to 22 C –Too warm!
>   • 23 - 40 C - Hot and Sweaty!

Would the values that are tested then change to the below? Would we still need to test the upper boundary in the first partition, or would we now ignore this as we have a lower boundary value?

```
For the lower invalid partition -2, -1, 0
For the first valid partition: -1, 0, 1  
For the second valid  partition:   10, 11, 12
For the third valid  partition:   15, 16, 17
For the fourth valid  partition:   19, 20, 21
For the fifth valid  partition:   22, 23, 24
For the upper invalid partition: 40, 41, 42
```

Thank you in advance - I think I have been over complicating things in my head and wracking my brain over this!

Answer (score 0):

3-value boundaries are not strictly required. E.g. in your example 9 and 10 are from the same equivalence class. Personally I'd either skip 9 completely or [randomize](http://qala.io/blog/randomized-testing.html) values across the whole partition.

In your "provided answers" the division "which cases relate to which partition" is arbitrary. Is 11 a "negative" boundary for ∞-10 range or a "positive" boundary for 11-15 range? There's no right answer. In practice you'll simply write these 8 checks w/o labelling which one is for which boundary:

```
* 10     - Icy
* 11, 15 - Chilled out
* 16, 19 - Cool man
* 20, 22 - Too warm
* 23     - Hot and Sweaty
```

If you decide to go with "3-value method" and check non-boundary values for each range you'll get additional 5 cases because there are 5 ranges.

Interestingly your "provided answer" is inconsistent. Every equivalence class has non-boundary value checked except for the "Hot and Sweaty" - it should've had 24 on the list resulting in 13 cases.

Disclaimer: this is an answer of a practitioner. I haven't read ISTQB, so if you need this info to pass a test (as opposed to using it in practice)  - use it with caution.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately this is for an exam!

Comment: Thanks again, my lecturer provided me with it!

Answer (score 0):

Jordan -

You have a point and I think the authors of the question you quote made a mistake. Following the ISTQB definition (CTFL 2018, Section 4.2.2): "three boundary values per boundary: the values before, at, and just over the boundary."

The problem is that **almost everywhere** you look, the examples given are of a single valid range, with invalid ranges on both sides ("almost everywhere" includes Jorgensen's book, "SW testing, a Craftsman's Approach", which the ISTQB syllabus quotes as reference in this case).

Following the ISTQB definition above, for EACH boundary value, you need to repeat the "before, at, and just over" analysis. For the first example, this would give you:

```
For 10 - we would test 9, 10, 11.  
For 11 - we would test 10 (already tested), 11 (already tested), 12  
For 15 - we would test 14, 15, 16
For 16 - we would test 15 (already tested), 16 (already tested), 17  
For 19 - we would test 18, 19, 20
For 20 - we would test 19 (already tested), 20 (already tested), 21
For 22 - we would test 21 (already tested), 22, 23

This would result in a a total of **14** test cases.
```

There is one way to explain the 12 tests in the answer, and for that you need to read "The Boundary Value Fallacy" by René Tuinhout, in the Sep 2018 issue of "Testing Experience" Magazine (good luck finding it... I tried a bit but the places I found all asked me to create an account).

Following that article, the values 12, 14 and the values 17,18 can be "merged" (that is, testing with one of them is sufficient to find the type of errors that are possible in code that defines boundaries). But I will be very surprised if the writers of the question (which I understand aims at the Foundation level) were thinking of this. It is definitely an advanced topic.